# Dollar weighed sampling for stock analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tick-by-tick stock data:

stock_code, price, volume, transaction_time

Each row represents one transaction.

I want to aggregate N number of rows (transactions) of Stock A such that:

Sum of price * volume over N rows > = 5,000,000

The aggregate "block" of Stock A would contain the average price and total volume of Stock A.  Each block should be bounded by the transaction_time of the first and last transactions.

I want to join a table of Stock B.  The rows of Stock B should have transaction_time between the first and last transaction_time of Stock A.

[image]

In this example, $5,024,675 of Stock A (0019.HK) was traded between 01:30:01 and 01:35:01 on 2019-09-10.  During 01:30:01 - 01:35:01, 12,500 shares of stock B(0087.HK) was traded for an average price of 12.088.

I am able to generate a CTE table for the Stock A:

```
With primary_instrument (ric, price,volume,dollarbar, ttime, index_for_joining)
AS
--ric represents stock code and ttime represents transaction time
--index_for_joining is created by removing millisecond data from ttime
(SELECT ric,price, volume,volume*price,ttime,minutesecindex
FROM  [firsttry].[dbo].[swirepacific5] where views='trdprc_1' and inst = 0 and RIC = '0019.HK'
)

SELECT TOP (1000) ric,price, volume,dollarbar, 
SUM(dollarbar) OVER (ORDER BY ttime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) as CUMSUM,
ttime,index_for_joining
from primary_instrument
```

and generate a CTE table for the secondary stock:

```
With secondary_instrument (ric, price,volume, index_for_joining)
AS
(SELECT ric,price, volume,minutesecindex
FROM  [firsttry].[dbo].[swirepacific5] where views='trdprc_1' and inst = 0 and RIC = '0087.HK'
)

SELECT TOP (1000) * from secondary_instrument
```

My questions are:

1. How do I separate CUMSUM into blocks of 5,000,000?  For performance and simplicity, I think it is not necessary to split a tick to make each sample exactly 5,000,000.  It is OK if the final tick causes CUMSUM to exceed 5,000,000.
2. How do I join the primary_instrument table, based on the start and end of index_for_joining to the secondary_instrument table?

The tick data, output for the 2 tables, and the "block of data" can be downloaded from this excel file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zufrp1giaoi4hfg/stockdata.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: There must be a simpler way to express this question, so other people can follow it.  Probably more focus on the data and less on your particular problem would help.  What does the data look like?  What do you want it to look like?  I think your question has this information, but it requires forensics to figure it out (and text tables rather than images) would help.

Comment: I simplified my problem and put it on the top as recommended (thanks).  I tried ASCII table but the rows appear to be too long and break formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer the second question first, whilst realizing the issues in hand may somewhat be complex to get across the line. In order to limit the time frame upon ttime/index_for_joining columns values, you can put multiple definitions under a single *With* statement, separated by comma (,).

So in your case, if you need to access *index_for_joining* column, which if I'm not wrong is the snapped timestamp to help extract time-frames out of the tick data, you can put the *secondary_instrument* CTE together with *primary_instrument*, and join both on the condition that the time-range matches (below I've joined them on RIC as the foreign key, but there's nothing stopping you from extending the *ON* condition of the join).

```
With primary_instrument (
    ric
,   price
,   volume
,   dollarbar
,   ttime
,   index_for_joining
) AS (
    Select  ric
    ,   price
    ,   volume
    ,   volume * price
    ,   ttime
    ,   minutesecindex
        From  [firsttry].[dbo].[swirepacific5]
        Where   views   =   'trdprc_1'
        And inst    =   0
        And RIC =   '0019.HK'
),
secondary_instrument (
    ric
,   price
,   volume
,   index_for_joining
) AS (
    SELECT  ric
    ,   price
    ,   volume
    ,   minutesecindex
        From    [firsttry].[dbo].[swirepacific5]
        Where   views   =   'trdprc_1'
        And inst    =   0
        And RIC =   '0087.HK'
)   Select  Top (1000)
        ric
    ,   price
    ,   volume
    ,   dollarbar
    ,   SUM(dollarbar) OVER (
            ORDER BY ttime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW
        )   As CUMSUM
    ,   ttime
    ,   index_for_joining
    ,   secondary_instrument.*
        From primary_instrument
        Inner   Join
            secondary_instrument
        On  primary_instrument.ric  =   secondary_instrument.ric
        ;
```

Regarding the first question - unless you have a way of splitting the volumes and putting them back together, the only option I am able to see is to write yet another recursive CTE to process the summation of the price from the first tick until the current row with a where clause to limit the summation (Sql Server supports both Range and Rows for partitioning clauses - but what you need here is the individual contract prices to be able to split the ticks and get as close as possible to your defined limit - 5 mil). Remember that such query is a costly process, firstly because its CTE, and secondly because every returned record is required to calculate the summation of the price for all its previous records. That is unless you introduce a new column and keep that value as new ticks come through.